# Renew an expired ssl certificate with a paid ssl certificate

Tags: nginx, ssl, ssl-certificate, odoo

I bought an SSL certificate because the one I had expired. How can I update this in letsencrypt cert bot,nginx?

I have 4 .crt files. Is it possible to simply overwrite the ssl in the existing example.pem file? Then I simply reload nginx?

What I mean, so here's the old example.pme file:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
pQAABAMARzBFAiEAtVUqdO5TvjFCWA2a/xo6TazLWI8ZJkOLx5/frToDLkgCIERW
W3ZxyNB7CP91DiNRJEsKJ9qu8fHv7sbqKGzlPXgwAHYAIkVFB1lVJFaWP6Ev8fdt
huAjJmOtwEt/XcaDXG7iDwIAAAFzpdCu0gAABAMARzBFAiBKo45S3xgIa9BXAlw1
HWUFvbotsD+bmDqkuTsPLIK7xwIhANsUGH9r8ZRFCbbRkwZLV7aVgIH42Xgs4y3F
fDHfYxbgAHUAQcjKsd8iRkoQxqE6CUKHXk4xixsD6+tLx2jwkGKWBvYAAAFzpdCu
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

in this example.pme file, I would simply delete the old ssl and copy the new one.
And after reload nginx.

In the example.pem file, I overwrote the old SSL with the new one, then reloaded and restarted nginx, but the browser still says that ssl has expired. What could be the problem?

Comment: If the certificate is new (not the old certificate just renewed) you also need to install the new private key because a new certificate usually comes with a new key (or have you reused the old key when generating the certificate request?).

Comment: Yes, I used the old key.

Comment: confirm me, it's enough if the file remains the same, I just copy/paste the new sll in place of the old one?

Comment: That doesn't sound right. There's a renewal process in place for a reason. We can't just modify the same file by cutting and pasting it.

Comment: If the certificate was issued by the same CA then yes, but even if you have bought the CA from the same company this doesn't necessarily means the issued CA is still the same. If the CA has changed you also need to update the used certificate chain.

Comment: I see, I found certbots tutorials on how to renew SSL, but I already have ssl because I bought it, what should I do in this case?

Comment: Here are some manual instructions, as you can see it's more than just cut and paste. You also need to concatenate the primary and intermediate certificates into one new file: https://www.digicert.com/kb/csr-ssl-installation/nginx-openssl.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can simply override files. There is no need to delete. And if you want to delete  files and place new files then you need to give necessary permission to the files.

You can try the following command for reload & restart nginx and reboot your system.

```
1. sudo /etc/init.d/nginx reload

2. sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart
```

OR

```
2.1 sudo /etc/init.d/nginx stop
2.2 sudo /etc/init.d/nginx start
```

Optional (reboot your system):

```
3. sudo reboot
```

Comment: In the example.pem file, I overwrote the old SSL with the new one, then reloaded and restarted nginx, but the browser still says that ssl has expired. What could be the problem?

Comment: You don't need to reboot the whole server to just change a certificate, that is cargo cult administration. In some webservers you don't even need to restart them to take into account new crypto materials. PS: the Linux world (love it or hate it) has switched to `systemd` mostly.